# Chart based on dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date-time

I created a dashboard for my work program tracking. I am trying to create a chart based on the dates so I can easily see how many people have done their competency. I have conditional formatting for the cells so they will turn yellow if they are within a month of being due and red if they are overdue.
I haven't been able to figure out a way to turn that data into a chart.
I thought about making a count formula based on the dates but nothing has worked yet. Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu6Tx.jpg)

Comment: Can you supply sample data and the kind of chart you are looking for?

Comment: The most easiest is,,, covert your data set into Table,,, will help you to dynamic updates to related objects, Then Make the SLICERS using the DATE column and finally make a chart,,, as soon you will hit the Particular Date Slicer ,, you will observe the changes over the Chart ,,, you may use helper data also for Weekly/Monthly report by using current DATE values☺

Answer (score 0):

welcome. A screenshot of your spreadsheet would help.

I'm assuming you have a column of names (A) and another with their respective deadline (B). The easiest way is to simply plot a histogram graph of column B. You can set a starting date by setting the underflow bin date in the x-axis properties. Set the bin width to 30 or 30.5 days. Remember dates are stored as the number of days past 1900/01/00. So the underflow bin date could be e.g. 44278 (2021/03/23) or 44256 (2021/03/01)

Alternatively may I suggest you bin the people into the months away from/past their deadline; then total the bins and plot a bar chart accordingly. A formula like this will give you the number of months away from the deadline

```
=INT((B2-NOW())/30)
```

Or more accurately, make bins in columns C through H with

```
=IF(AND(B2 <= EDATE(NOW(),3), B2 > EDATE(NOW(),2)), 1, 0)
```

Decreasing 3 and 2 by 1 each in each column, or adjust automatically for the column / bin number

```
=IF(AND(B2 <= EDATE(NOW(),3 -COLUMN()+3), B2 > EDATE(NOW(),2 -COLUMN()+3)), 1, 0)
```

Now total and plot a bar chart.

Comment: I'll test that out. I was able to link the data I'm trying to chart. I can figure out the chart, it's counting the totals. A pie chart would work, or if I can get the data I can throw it into a gnant chart to see when people are coming due. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I created another section that had total, due and overdue. I used the count for the entire number, and then counting(table),today() "<=" 330) and another for over 365. Then I created the chart based on those numbers.
Thank you so much for the other suggestions. It got me looking in the right direction.